# HTML5/javascriptで表示の切り替えをしたいのですが、find()の使い方がいまいちわかりません。

Tags: javascript, html5, spring-boot

SpringBoot＋HTML5で勉強中になります。

■HTML５

```
<section id="testsection" th:each="testinfo, stat:${testInfos}" >
    // stat.indexが0の場合
    <div class="testsection active">①
        <div th:text="${testinfo.ラベル}" >
        <div th:text="${testinfo.データ}" >
    // stat.indexが0でない場合
    <div class="testsection">②
        <div th:text="${testinfo.ラベル}" >
        <div th:text="${testinfo.データ}" >
</section>
```

このようにしていて、activeの場合にスタイルCSSで「display: block;」となるようにしています。※①が表示されて②は非表示の状態

ここで、あるボタンが押された場合に①を非表示、②を表示にしたいのです。
ボタンのイベント処理をjavascript側
（A）でactiveな①を取得して、
（B）で①をdisplay: noneにし、
（C)ですべての①～②を取得し、
（D）でボタンの番号（changeNo）をINDEXとしたものをdisplay: block;にして
表示させれないかと思うのですが、（B)の後に（C）を取得しても①の分が取得できません。
なにか足りない処理などありますでしょうか。

■javascript

```
function change(changeNo) {
    // 言語
    var activeInfo = $('#testsection').find('.testsection.active');（A）
    activeInfo.removeClass('active');（B）
    var nonactiveInfo = $('#testsection').find('.testsection');（C）
    $(nonactiveInfo[changeNo]).addClass('active');（D）
}
```

Comment: (C)の記述は `.active` の有無にかかわらず `.textsection` を選択するので、(A)(B)を実行してもしなくても①②の両方が含まれます（[例](https://jsfiddle.net/y86sm9bp/)）。ですから「（B)の後に（C）を取得しても①の分が取得できません」とは思えないのですが、どのように確認されたのでしょうか？(D)の結果が想定と違うのかなと思いましたが、「ボタンの番号（changeNo）をINDEXとしたものを」に相当する記述がコードにありませんし、そもそも(D)の行は括弧の対応が崩れています。こちらもコードを修正していただけませんか？

Comment: いくつか質問です。`div` が閉じていないように見えますが、実際は大丈夫ですか？  SpringBoost ではなく、jQueryの質問に見えますが、いかがですか？  [前の質問](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/27940/html%e3%81%ae%e8%a1%a8%e7%a4%ba%e3%81%ae%e5%88%87%e3%82%8a%e6%9b%bf%e3%81%88%e3%82%92%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)と同じ質問ではないですか？  (同じでしたら、より具体的なこちらの方がよい質問だと思うので、向うは削除でよいと思います)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！すみません。$(nonactiveInfo[changeNo]).addClass('active');（D）部分を修正しました。また、確認方法としては（A）、（B）間にvar len = activeInfo.length;をいれ、ブラウザでF12にてブレイクかけて確認したところ、1となっていた次第です。

Comment: それは(A)で取得した件数を確認するコードですから、①の分だけカウントして1になるのは正しいのでは？「（‌​B)の後に（C）を取得しても①の分が取得できません」という話なのですから、(C)で取得した件数を確認するべきでしょうし、件数だけでなくデバッガや `console.log()` 等で中身を確認したほうが確実ではないでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！すみません、何度かブラウザのキャッシュを削除し、起動しなおすことで期待値を取得できました。お騒がせしました。また、console.log() なども利用していきたいと思います！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(nonactiveInfo[changeNo])というセレクタでは特定できないと思います。
いったんセレクタ文字列を変数に入れて、それを$(変数)とした方がいいでしょう。

しかも、やりたいことを実現するのには.find()を使う必要がなさそうな気がします。
もっとシンプルに考えてみてはどうでしょう？

①あるボタンが押されたとき、change()を実行する。
　何個めの.testsectionを.activeにするか引数を渡す。
②.active（何個めかは関係ない）のclassを外す。
③引数の番号の.testsectionにclassを追加する。

```
function change(changeNo) {
    $('.testsection.active').removeClass('active');
    var nonactiveInfo = '.testsection:nth-child(' + changeNo + ')';
    $(nonactiveInfo).addClass('active');
}
```

ただ、:nth-childは連続した兄弟要素の中での順序で指定することになるので、
提示のHTMLとは異なりほかの場所にも同じclassがあったりするなら
また別のセレクタにしないといけませんね。

【追記】
コメントのとおり、動作しました。
[サンプル](http://codepen.io/mayo31/pen/grdrVL)

じゃあ何がいけないのかな…と考えると、引数が合っていないのかな？
・0または1以外の存在しないindexを渡してしまっている？
・関係ない文字列やオブジェクトを渡してしまっている？

Comment: `nonactiveinfo` がjQueryオブジェクトの時、`nonactiveinfo[changeNo]`とすることで `changeNo` 番目のDOM要素が取得できますから、それを`$()` に渡せばその要素を操作することはできますね。

Comment: 失礼しました。仰る通りで、質問者様の提示のコードどおりで操作できました。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！すみません、何度かブラウザのキャッシュを削除し、起動しなおすことで期待値を取得できました。お騒がせしました。